# Alternate for DigesterLoader.createDigester(url) in digester3

Tags: java, apache-commons-digester

To be precise my question would be what is the alternate method for `Digester.createLoader(url)` in new `Digester3`?

**commons-digester:1.8.1 code**

```
    URL url;
    ClassLoader curClassLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    url = curClassLoader.getResource("filepath");

    if (url != null) {          
        Digester tempDigester = DigesterLoader.createDigester(url);
        ----
        ----
        }
```

Now I have upgraded `commons-digester-1.8.1` to `org.apcahe.commons.Digester3-3.2` and in new jar I don't see any method as `createDigester(ur);`

How can I replace `DigesterLoader.createDigester(url)` using new API to get Digester object in return.

**commons-digester:3.2 code**

```
    URL url;
    ClassLoader curClassLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    url = curClassLoader.getResource("filepath");

    if (url != null) {          
        Digester tempDigester = ???;
        ----
        ----
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't checked exactly what the 1.8 version does, but assuming your URL resolves to a stream of XML based rules then something like this should do the trick:

```
import org.apache.commons.digester3.Digester;
import org.apache.commons.digester3.binder.DigesterLoader;
import org.apache.commons.digester3.binder.RulesModule;
import org.apache.commons.digester3.xmlrules.FromXmlRulesModule;

final URL url = curClassLoader.getResource("filepath");

RulesModule rules = new FromXmlRulesModule() {
  @Override
  protected void loadRules() {
    loadXMLRules(url);
  }
};

DigesterLoader loader = DigesterLoader.newLoader(rules);
Digester digester = loader.newDigester();
```

Note you probably have to make your URL final to use it within the anonymous subclass.

Tested with the following simple rules file:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE digester-rules PUBLIC '-//Apache Commons //DTD digester-rules XML V1.0//EN' 'http://commons.apache.org/digester/dtds/digester-rules-3.0.dtd'>
<digester-rules>
  <pattern value='data'>
    <object-create-rule classname='test.digester.BasicTest$ClassA'/>
    <bean-property-setter-rule pattern='name' propertyname='name'/>
  </pattern>
</digester-rules>
```

Requires the DOCTYPE declaration, but works with or without the XML declaration. Running without the DOCTYPE gives:

```
Parse Error at line 1 column 17: Document root element "digester-rules", must match DOCTYPE root "null"
```

Comment: @PraveenKumarMekala works for me with a quick test file - what is the contents of the xml rules you are trying to read?

Comment: am digging into my exception and got doubt, is it mandatory to define  <!DOCTYPE digester-rules PUBLIC
  "-//Apache Commons //DTD digester-rules XML V1.0//EN"
  "http://commons.apache.org/digester/dtds/digester-rules-3.0.dtd">  in my xml files?

Comment: @PraveenKumarMekala yes, the DOCTYPE is required - see sample rules above. Can you post a simple version of the rules file you are trying to load?

Comment: @PraveenKumarMekala Neither of your xml snippets have closing tags - assuming that is just a cut and paste error. Added those tags and a DOCTYPE - need that as per earlier comment - then loads fine for me so not sure what to suggest. What is the full stack trace of your exception?